# Complex OData Query in ASP.NET API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odata

I need some help on performing a select query based on a result of a sub query in the ASP.NET MVC Controller.
by default the Get method returns the list of objects... for example:

```
    public IQueryable<Order> GetOrdersByID(string id)
    {
        return db.Orders.Where(e => e.orderId == id);
    }
```

If I want to (`select all products where product id is in (select product IDS from orders where order id = ID)`)

How can I achieve that in the controller with a method like:

```
    public IQueryable<Product> GetOrdersByID(string id)
    {
        /// This line is wrong what is the correct one please....
        return db.Products.Where(p => p.id IN (db.Orders
                          .Where(e => e.orderId == id)); 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you return `IQueryable<Product>` from the `GetOrdersByID` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IEnumerable<T>`'s `Any` extension method here:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetOrdersByID(string id)
{
     return db.Products
           .Where(p => db.Orders.Any(i => i.orderId == p.id && i.orderId == id));
}
```

**NOTICE:** Take on account that the **`Any`** method has the complexity of O(N) and the full solution actually has the complexity of O(N•M) because for each `Product`, in the worst-case, you might scan the full `Orders` collection.